# Why the "wc" command called in the following program doesn't output any message in terminal?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm trying to get a feeling about how pipe works in Linux. I wrote the following program, compiled it and then run it in terminal. The program exits normally without errors, but it didn't print out any message. Is there anything wrong?

PS: this code snippet is  from MIT's xv6 operating system course.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int p[2];
    char *argv[2];
    argv[0] = "wc";
    argv[1] = 0;
    pipe(p);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(0);
        dup(p[0]);
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
        execvp("/bin/wc", argv);
    } else {
        write(p[1], "hello world\n", 12);
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably check return values, like from `execvp`. On my Ubuntu machine `command -v wc` returns `/usr/bin/wc`. Also see [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639)

Comment: @jww Thanks! My system also has "wc" in `usr/bin/wc`.

Comment: @jww,  The `exec*()` functions do not return anything unless the function fails.  So if it returns should always call `perror()` then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the posted code fails to check for when `fork()` fails.  In such a case, should call `perror()` and then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: @user3629249- See the [`execvp (3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp). I'm guessing (and it is just a guess), `execvp` is failing and `errno` is  `ENOENT`.

Comment: I've run the code with many modifications.  The main problem is the piped string from 'main' is not getting to the 'wc' program.  Also,  'wc' is expecting a file name, not a random string.

Comment: I tried your code unmodified, and it produced the same result as `echo "hello world" | wc` with the minor difference that the output sometimes comes after the new command line prompt. In addition to checking for errors in `execvp()`, `pipe()`, `fork()`, `dup()` and `write()`, you should call `waitpid()` on the child. And `int main()` is bad c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. passes the name of a local file, rather than some random string AND the file name is terminated with a NUL byte
4. you will need to modify the passed file name to a file that is in your current directory
5. notice the length passed to `write()` includes the trailing NUl byte

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    int p[2];
    char *argv[3];
    argv[0] = "wc";
    argv[1] = "--files0-from=-";
    argv[2] = (char *) NULL;
    if( pipe(p) != 0 )
    {
        perror( "pipe failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch( pid )
    { 
        case -1:
        perror( "fork failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        break;

        case 0:
        close(0);
        if( dup2(p[0], 0) != 0 )
        {
            perror( "dup2 failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
        execvp("/usr/bin/wc", argv);
        perror( "execvp failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        break;

        default:
        write(p[1], "untitled2.c", 12);
        close(p[0]);
        wait( NULL );
        close(p[1]);
    }
}
```

Note: the `untitled2.c` is this source file.

a run of the program results in:

```
47 101 818 untitled2.c
```

Answer (score 0):

The command wc prints the file name after the number of rows, chars and words only if the argoument of wc is an actual file:

`$ wc hello_word.txt
   1 2 12 hello_word.txt`

In fact neither doing the redirection from the terminal will print out the message

`$ echo "hello word" | wc
   1 2 11`

If you prefer you can simply print out the message on stdout on the child process before writing on the pipe

```
if (fork() == 0) {
  .. 
} else {
    printf("Message: 'hello world'\n");
    write(p[1], "hello world\n", 12);
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
}
```